# how to add a blank row to contact list in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
<aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<ul class="list-group">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{! '#contact/' + contact.Id }">
                <p>{!contact.Name}</p>
                <p>{!contact.Phone}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </aura:iteration>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to do it

```
   var contactslist = component.get('v.contacts'); //get the list variable
   contactslist.push({'sobjectType':'contact',
                'FirstName': '',
                'LastName': ''});//add a new contact sobject instance
    component.set('v.contacts', contactslist);//set it back on the list attribute again
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: can you exactly tell whats not working? are you seeing errors? or the blank row does not show up in UI?

Comment: iam seeing error

Comment: Add the error to the question. Its difficult to suggest solutions without seeing the errors